# Find functions such that there is no solution for a formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, roots

While working on an application I stumbled on a problem that is tough for me as I don't know differential equations well.

I want to find conditions for a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^{*}_{+}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$\frac{f(x)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{f'(x)} = \frac{x\ln\frac{c}{x}}{2}$ does not have any solution for all possible values of $c \in (x, \infty)$

For example $f(x) = x$ does not work as:

$x^\frac{3}{2} = \frac{x\ln\frac{c}{x}}{2}$

when

$x = W(\sqrt{c})^{2}$

I am curious what kind of mathematical tool should I use here to get started.

Comment: The ODE has the general solution $$\dfrac1{\sqrt f(x)}=\log(\log(\frac cx))+C.$$ You can check it by substitution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for the reply. Indeed, that solves the ODE. I am interested in kind of the opposite problem. I want to understand when does it happen that for all $x$:  $\frac{f(x)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{f'(x)} \neq \frac{x\ln\frac{c}{x}}{2}$.

It's possible to come up with a family of such functions for example by solving:

 $f'(x) = f(x)^{\frac{3}{2}}(a + \frac{2}{x\ln\frac{c}{x}})$ for $a \neq 0$.


One could obviously suggest $g$ s.t. $\forall x$:

$g(x) > \frac{x\ln\frac{c}{x}}{2}$

and then solve

$\frac{f(x)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{f'(x)} = g(x)$

I'd like to have a simpler tool.